# Java - I keep losing references to my Global class

Tags: java, global

So I have a `Global` class that is supposed to hold all sorts of data that can be accessed from all of my files. `Global` looks like this:

```
public class Global{
public static int rules = 0;
public static String data;
public static int score;
public static int speed = 0;
//etc...
}
```

I set and get things to it by doing `Global.x = ___` and such.

However, I recently cleaned up a memory leak in my project, where the view (`View A`) that I created lived longer than it was supposed to.

This `View A` assigned `Global.x`.

Now, once I move to `View B`, `View A` is GC'd.

However, `Global.x` no longer has a value.

Is this expected behavior from Java? If so, how can I assign a variable to my Global class from `View A` and assure that it is kept even after `View A` dies.

Or am I just doing something wrong somewhere else?

I figured I'd ask just in case I'm overlooking something, but it's probably the latter.

Comment: What do you mean by a view?

Comment: An Android `SurfaceView`. I thought my questions would be a generic Java question, so I didn't want to get into the specifics too much

Comment: Are you creating a `Global` instance in `A` view and setting the data there or this `Global` keeps the attributes as `public static` (by the way, this last one is a very bad design)?

Comment: No, I'm not creating an instance of `Global`. `Global` keeps the variables as `public static` like the snippet above

Comment: Ignoring that this is a really bad practice, nothing is going to "unset" those static values; `Global` will live until the classloader that loaded it is GC'd.

Comment: this is a bad design. If you need to have Global Data and it can be accessed for read/write data by multiple classes - there might be lots of complexities like Data Consistency. If not by multiple classes and just once , then create a Singleton object which would load at startup (I dont know how you would do it in Andriod) and then write global data to it

Comment: From the code provided, nothing can be said for sure. Your problem lies elsewhere in your code. It would be better to debug the operations made between moving from `A` to `B` view and check what's launching and causing the odd behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design issues aside;

There are really only two ways I can think of that would make the garbage collection of `View A` have effect on the value of `Global.x`;

- `Global.x` is (or uses) a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to `View A` or something that is garbage collected along with it.
- `View A` has a finalizer that changes the value of `Global.x`.

Neither of these sound likely (although, of course I can't see your code)

My best bet is that you should look elsewhere for the error. Since global state variables are inherently not thread safe in any way, your problem may very well be threading related.

Comment: Okay. I'll buy that it lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The problem as you've stated it is missing facts that would help you solve your particular issue.  Consider pasting the smallest Java code that you can create that reproduces the issue.  Having said that, your design is bad, and you should consider using a singleton.

```
public class Global { 

    private Global INSTANCE = new Global();
    private int speed;

    private Global() { 
        // whatever you do to initialize...
        speed = 65;
    }

    public Global getInstance() { 
    }

    public int getSpeed() { 
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) { 
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

and from whatever scope you are in, you can say:

```
Global.getInstance().getSpeed();
```

or

```
Global.getInstance().setSpeed(25);
```

etc...

Comment: That's not the solution to original problem, but it might *solve* the problem in OP's design.

Comment: Using a singleton is no better practice than what he's doing now with his class with `static` values.

Comment: making it thread safe is not better practice?  his stated issue appears bogus.

Comment: It's not threadsafe as you wrote it (except for the initial instantiation). That aside, yes, agreed - something else is going on in his code.

Comment: true - its not.  i see now you edited your comment.  i was simply trying to lead him to a better design..

Comment: *No, I'm not creating an instance of Global* (from OP's comments), so he/she's wrong or the problem lies elsewhere (and not in the design)